# Libcurl.dll error with Git push

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket

Recently I installed Git (Using Bit bucket for repository). I configured everything according to different guides I found on the net, but whenever I use the command `git push -u origin --all` I get the following error:

> The procedure entry point curl_multi_timeout could not be located in the dynamic link library libcurl.dll

Comment: what is your operating system ? i would start by reinstalling git

Comment: Windows 7 @WillemD'haeseleer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like it's an [OpenOffice conflict from their libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-07/0179.html). From my understanding, Openoffice put an old libcurl.dll in the system directory.

Try to remove libcurl.dll from `C:\Windows\sysWOW64` and/or `C:\Windows\System32` (Reinstalling Git or uninstalling OpenOffice doesn't seem to fix the problem).

Comment: Thanks! I removed libcurl.dll from C:\Windows\System32 and after that it worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks - it worked for me too. Should I be worried about side effects on Windows Office?

Answer (score 31):

- Go to the folder where Git is installed (**defalut**: `C:\Program Files\Git`).
- **Copy** the file `"libcurl.dll"` in Git installation folder (`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\libcurl.dll`).
- **Paste** it in location where the git.exe exists (`C:\Program Files\Git\libexec\git-core`).

This should fix the issue, since now it will check for the lib in current executing folder before falling back to systems folder.

Comment: Excellent! In my corporate environment I have a custom libcurl.dll placed in my windows folders by some software used for logging into corporate systems. Needless to say, I cannot get rid of it, or replace it with other version. Copying the `libcurl.dll from `git/bin` to `git/libexec/git-core` allows me to work with git! ;)

Answer (score 2):

As a side note for anyone using pre-built libcurl in their projects: this can be caused because you have **libcurl.dll** in the root of the folder you are trying to push. Windows will load the library in your project folder before the one with Git first.

The solution is simple -- remove or move **libcurl.dll** in your project.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same thing with the windows application installed in your local appdata directory.

To copy the file from :

```
C:\Users\YOUR-WINDOWS-COUNT\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_xxxx-A-BIG-NUMBER-XXXXXXXXXXXXX\libexec\git-core\bin\libcurl.dll
```

to the directory:

```
C:\Users\YOUR-WINDOWS-COUNT\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_xxxx-A-BIG-NUMBER-XXXXXXXXXXXXX\libexec\git-core
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps (this worked for my 64 bit win7):

```
a) Copy libcurl.dll from C:\Windows\sysWOW64\libcurl.dll 
   to some temporary location.
b) Remove libcurl.dll from C:\Windows\sysWOW64\libcurl.dll
c) Try cloning repository from Git Windows App.
```

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove libcurl.dll from C:\Windows
2. After that it worked

Answer (score 0):

I was setting things up for http access.  I was getting a similar error (libcurl-4.dll is missing) on the client.    The fix turned out to be that some of the housekeeping files deep in the repository tree *on the server* were owned by 'root' rather than 'apache'.  Correcting that  corrected the missing curl error on the client.

Answer (score 0):

For me (`64 bit Windows7`), uninstalling GIT and reinstalling it was the only solution that worked.