# Libcurl.dll error with Git Push even after deleting Libcurl.dll

Tags: git, dll

Followed instructions here:
[Libcurl.dll error with Git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694502/libcurl-dll-error-with-git-push)
and this initially worked. Now the exact same error occurs but there is no Libcurl.dll anymore. There was a Libcurl.dll in Git/bin but I renamed that to dll-save so not sure where the library is. I tried shutting down the MINGW32 application which I was using to access Git and restarting it but get same error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the [old and obsolete msysgit 1.9.5 form git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/download/win), try and unzip wherever you want [`PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe).
Add the Git installation path to your `%PATH%`. For instance:

```
set PATH=<path/to/PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit>/cmd;%PATH%
```

It does include a `mingw64/bin/mibcurl-4.dll`, which should work just fine.

I explain why that 64 version of the new Git for Windows came to be in "[Why is it that if you download Git 2.0 from the net, you always get a 1.9.4 installer package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309)".

Comment: Thanks, I will try this but I am puzzled about the error for two reasons: Firstly, I did have things working and and secondly, the error message must at least be misleading because of the complete absence now of the dll it refers to.